# hyperrefs have a different spacing when written inside a macro

Tags: spacing, macros, hyperref

Let's say I want to make a hyperlink like this:

```
A link is placed \href{www.google.com}{here} to google.
```

[image: render "A link is placed \href{www.google.com}{here} to google."]

Then I decide to make a macro for that:

```
\newcommand\Myhref[2]{
\href{#1}{#2}
}
A link is placed \Myhref{www.google.com}{here} to google.
```

[image: render "A link is placed \Myhref{www.google.com}{here} to google."]

The spacing is wrong for the second example.

The motivation is that I want to apply a very custom style (with underlines and colouring and font-sizes) that is too complicated for the `\hypersetup` global style. So I write a macro that applies the style to the hyperlink text. But the spacing is all wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate:[What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864)?

Comment: In this simple case, it suffices to say `\let\Myhref\href`. But, you probably have a bigger scope.

Comment: I do not agree that it is a duplicate. **(1)** someone searching for an answer to this problem would never find the linked question unless they already know the solution. **(2)** The linked question does not explain in any way that % signs are a solution to _this_ sort of problem.  **(3)** It isn't obvious why having extra newlines (from the macro definition) should have _any_ effect on spacing, and the linked question does not explain this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaving end of line spaces. Put `%` at the end at two places like

```
\newcommand\Myhref[2]{%<-------- here
\href{#1}{#2}%        <-------- and here
}
```

Then you are good to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\Myhref[2]{%<-------- here
\href{#1}{#2}%        %<-------- and here
}

\begin{document}
  A link is placed \href{www.google.com}{here} to google.

  A link is placed \Myhref{www.google.com}{here} to google.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see by trying it that this solves the problem, but why does it work?  Doesn't the macro simply insert the newlines into the text when the replacement is made?  Such newlines wouldn't affect the final spacing.  So why does getting rid of the newlines have any effect?

Comment: Ah, the answer is that whitespace regions in the source are _only_ reduced to a single space _before_ macro substitutions are done.